Block xdg-settings from being altered on package install
Running on ArchLinux, and it's incredibly frustrating that Chromium, upon install, sets itself as the default browser using xdg-settings (which many programs prefer over $BROWSER).
Is there a method by which I can block alterations to my settings? Installing a new package should not result in any preferences being altered.
